# Wildcards in HTML5 data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sizzle

Is it possible to find all DOM elements with jQuery with wildcards in the attribute name?

Consider the following HTML:

```
<input 
     id="val1" 
     type="text" 
     data-validate-required 
     data-validate-minlength="3" 
     data-validate-email />
```

What I am trying to achieve is to find all dom nodes with an attribute name starting with `data-validate-`

As far as I understand the wildcards described [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) are concerned with "value" of the attribute.

The reason for this is - I want to find out which elements should be validated at all - and afterwards find out which validation parameters (like -email) comes in play.

Thanks

Comment: For what I've seen in lot of modules, people tend to add another attribute with just the prefix. HTH.

Comment: @ambs So it is not possible to use wildcards in the attribute name and people already use the "prefix-" as a selector to overcome this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom pseudoclass to e.g. match attribute names against a regexp: http://jsfiddle.net/hN6vx/.

```
jQuery.expr.pseudos.attr = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    var regexp = new RegExp(arg);
    return function(elem) {
        for(var i = 0; i < elem.attributes.length; i++) {
            var attr = elem.attributes[i];
            if(regexp.test(attr.name)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
$(":attr('^data-')")
```

Comment: I was about to answer this, but you beat me to it. pseudo-classes can be very useful.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted this approach. Even though I think I will have to refactor my code after all in order to avoid performance problems with large DOMs...

Answer (score 3):

Because JQuery relies heavily on [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath), and XPath does not support wildcard attribute selection - it is not possible without the overhead you're looking to avoid.

There's always the possibility of creating your own selector, just to keep things clean:

```
//adds the :dataValidate selector
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
    dataValidate: function(obj){
        var i,dataAttrs=$(obj).data()
        for (i in dataAttrs) {
                if (i.substr(0,8)=='validate') return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
})
```

Which will allow you to use :dataValidate in your normal jQuery selectors:

```
$(".element:dataValidate .etc")
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rZXZ3/

Comment: Thank you - equally good answer like below! I chose the more "generic" approach as "answered". Thanks for the xpath reference - now it is more clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop over the atributes:

```
$('.element').each(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function(i, att){
     if(att.name.indexOf('data-validate')==0){
         console.log(att.name);
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I already can get all "data-" attributes with `$('.sth').data()` and iterate the result. But this seems like an overhead to me. So basically the answer is: It is not possible with jQuery standard selectors and my attribute wildcard idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` method and [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset) object:

> Allows access, both in reading and writing mode, to all the custom data attributes (data-*) set on the element. It is a map of DOMString, one entry for each custom data attribute.

```
$("input").filter(function(){
    var state = false;
    for (i in this.dataset) 
        if (i.indexOf('validate') > -1) state = true;

    return state             
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pxpfa/

Comment: Nice but for anyone for whom browser support is an issue, make sure you check the compatibility table on that link: e.g. for IE it's only in version 11 (which isn't even out yet)